# Multiple redirect rows to different outputs in SSIS

Tags: ssis, bids

Hi is it possible to have multiple redirect rows (when error) in an SSIS control to different outputs depending on which column is in error?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

For every data flow  component in ssis ,there is only `one error flow path`  and more over its pretty difficult to find which column generated error as there is no straight forward way to find the column name in SSIS .

At the most u can use a script component to find the column name

```
 this.ComponentMetaData.InputCollection[Row.ErrorColumn].Name
```

but the above code gives you the `lineage ID` .Unfortunately with the lineage id ,its difficult to get the column names.